# Payment fee from Iphone app

Tags: iphone, payment

I'm developing an Iphone app that allows to buy products and pay via credit card.
Do i have to pay some fee from every payment that being maid inside the app?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, provided that the products are not digital (i.e. real tangible items), or features within the app.

It is perfectly fine to accept credit card payments for goods (for example the eBay and Amazon apps), without having to pay the 30% fee to Apple.